# When using ggplot2, can I set the color of histogram bars without potentially obscuring low values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When calling `geom_histogram()` with the `color`, and `fill` arguments, `ggplot2` will confusingly paint the whole x-axis range, making it impossible to visually distinguish between a low value and a zero value.

Running the following code:

```
ggplot(esubset, aes(x=exectime)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) +
theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,20), limits=c(0,20))
```

will result in

[image: a histogram w/o color attributes]

This is visually very unappealing. To fix that, I'd like to instead use

```
ggplot(esubset, aes(x=exectime)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5,
colour='black', fill='gray') + theme_bw() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,20), limits=c(0,20))
```

which would result in

[image: a histogram with color attributes]

The problem is that I'll have no way of distinguishing whether `exectime` contains values past 10, as a few occurrences of 12, for example, would be hidden behind the horizontal line spanning the whole x-axis.

Comment: you mind using logaritmic scaling ?

Comment: perhaps do the aggregation manually? you are causing this behavior with the `limits` parameter.

Comment: very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128090/remove-baseline-color-for-geom-histogram

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `coord_cartesian` instead of `scale_x_continuous`. `coord_cartesian` sets the axis range without affecting how the data are plotted. Even with `coord_cartesian`, you can still use `scale_x_continuous` to set the `breaks`, but `coord_cartesian` will override any effect of `scale_x_continuous` on how the data are plotted.

In the fake data below, note that I've added data for a few very small bars.

```
set.seed(4958)
dat = data.frame(value=c(rnorm(5000, 10, 1), rep(15:20,1:6)))

ggplot(dat, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, color="black", fill="grey") + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(5,25), breaks=5:25) + 
  ggtitle("scale_x_continuous")

ggplot(dat, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, color="black", fill="grey") + 
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(5,25)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=5:25) +
  ggtitle("coord_cartesian")
```

[image]

As you can see in the plots above, if there are bins with count=0 *within the data range*, ggplot will add a zero-line, even with `coord_cartesian`. This makes it difficult to see the bar at 15 of height=1. You can make the border thinner with the `lwd` argument ("linewidth") so that smaller bars will be less obscured:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, color="black", fill="grey", lwd=0.3) + 
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(5,25)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=5:25) +
  ggtitle("coord_cartesian")
```

[image]

One other option is to pre-summarise the data and plot using `geom_bar` in order to get spaces between the bars and thereby avoid the need for border lines to mark bar edges:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

bins = seq(floor(min(dat$value)) - 1.75, ceiling(max(dat$value)) + 1.25, 0.5)

dat.binned = dat %>% 
  count(bin=cut(value, bins, right=FALSE)) %>%   # Bin the data
  complete(bin, fill=list(n=0)) %>%              # Restore empty bins and fill with zeros
  mutate(bin = rollmean(bins,2)[-length(bins)])  # Convert bin from factor to numeric with value = mean of bin range

ggplot(dat.binned, aes(bin, n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=hcl(240,100,30)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:21)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using `after_stat` in your y `aes` to check if the plotted value is higher than 0 otherwise it will be replaced by NA to make sure it is removed from the histogram. This makes it possible to see differences between small values and zeros in a histogram like this (data from @eipi10):

```r
set.seed(4958)
dat = data.frame(value=c(rnorm(5000, 10, 1), rep(15:20,1:6)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = value,
                y = ifelse(after_stat(count) > 0, after_stat(count), NA))) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, color="black", fill="grey") + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(5,25), breaks=5:25)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

As you can see there is a difference between the smaller values and 0.